# What is the difference In variables and constant in regards to their significance when I can just make multiple "permanent" variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, memory, constants

I was a bit confused between the implementation of constants in python. Apparently it is easier to limit bugs with constants and what not because constants store info that doesn't change. However, cant you essentially do that with variables as well just make multiple variables when they are subject to change so they stay constant over time?

At first I thought it may be because constants are all capitalized which tells other programmers not to potentially change anything. However it seems like constants are not known for that function.

Answer (score 1):

Other languages enforce rules around constants such that their values cannot be (easily) changed in code.
Python doesn't know constants but some IDEs will recognize something like
`MY_CONSTANT: str = "don't change me"`
...as a constant. And the all-caps format alone can help constants be recognized as such by programmers (I don't know where you have the info from that constants are not known for that).

So even though Python doesn't enforce rules around constants, they are used (and useful) by convention

Comment: My prof said constants are known for preventing bug as they are easily "mass changeable" and easier to identify and that's why they are important in coding. However I was a bit confused a variables essentially do the same.

Comment: Functionally, in Python, you are right - But the convention of using constants makes sense because it means using a "different class of variables" that serve a distinct purpose - namely not to change their values, which regular variables aren't exactly known for (hence their name)